# GPU computation difference between rendering and cloth baking

Tags: texture-baking, gpu, cloth-simulation

After reading some articles on blender speed, I see that using CUDA enabled GPU computing will be of help in rendering.

I am trying to stitch a shirt on human .obj file. For that I bake 60 frames for it to fall on the human correctly. It takes about 20 seconds for the bake. I'd want to host it real time. 
youtube link of the same : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHDdtaMm1rA

Can I use GPU computing to reduce the bake time just like rendering time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the OpenGL viewport preview, GPU Acceleration inside Blender can only be used currently for rendering with the Cycles Render Engine using either [CUDA on NVidia GPUs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda) or [OpenCL for AMD Graphics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl) cards on certain supported hardware. OpenCL acceleration may also be used on the compositor for image processing.

Physics baking, particles and cloth simulation and all other areas currently only use CPU, as far as I know.